# Inserting a value to a table which is present in more than one database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Could someone let me know how to insert a set of values into a table across different databases .

Example : I have a table by name **TABLE** inside **Database1** , **Database2** ....

Is there a way where I can insert values into the **TABLE** present in both the databses.

I tried doing

```
Insert into Database1,Database2.Table(type)values('1');
```

But it did not work .

Thanks for your help

Comment: how about creating triggers for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Table names, column names, etc. cannot be dynamic in mysql, you can try to create dynamic queries

```
$databases  = list of dbs;
foreach ($databases as $db){
  $query = "Insert into".$db.".tableName()....."
}
```

Comment: I wish it was so easy .. But the thing is that the database list is dynamic .. There is no way I can tell whether the list has one database in it or 10 ..

Answer (score 0):

since you are using php you can use `mysqli_select_db(connection,dbname);` to select different database using it.

for Eg.

```
    //create a connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect("host","user","password","db_name");

    //list of databases
    $databases = "Your Array of database";

    foreach ($databases as $database){

        // Change database to $database
        mysqli_select_db($conn,$database);

        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect :" . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        // code for $database eg. - your insert query...
    }
```